# Excel macro to open file with partial filename

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried looking on various forums and cannot seem to find a solution that fits my needs.

I have a file "BABERs FORMULAS - 24 Jan 2017 - Rev 079 11-27.xlsm". I use a macro to save the changes to the file which adds the date, revision number and timestamp to the filename. The file is located at the following path "D:\FORMULAS".

The macro I have is as below but this then gives me a Run-time error '1004' and says to check that the spelling of the file name and verify the location is correct.

```
Dim fname as Variant
fname = Dir("D:\FORMULAS\BABERs FORMULAS*")

If fname <> "" then
    Workbooks.open (fname)
End If
```

Any ideas where I could be going wrong? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify the path when opening a workbook - `Workbooks.Open "D:\FORMULAS\" & fname`

Comment: @YowE3K damn you're fast today :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like the code below:

```
Dim fname As Variant
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "D:\FORMULAS\"
fname = Dir(myPath & "BABERs FORMULAS*")

If fname <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open (myPath & fname)
End If
```

Comment: I am linking this code to a button on the Quick Access Toolbar, however, when I change the code to suit the above coding it gave an error message as follows: Cannot run the macro 'PERSONAL.XLSB!Formula_Spreadsheet'. This macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: @Baber62 what error? Copy this entire code to your button, I ran it without getting any errros

Comment: @ Shai Radio My bad I hadn't realised that I had changed the name of the macro from Formula_Spreadsheet to FormulaOpen. The coding works fine. Thanks, appreciated.