# How to find, open, and refer to workbook with partial name

Tags: vba, excel, partial

I am trying to use a partial name match to locate a template file (full name `On-Call Audit Sheet VXX` where VXX is the version) that gets updated from the current workbook with the macro I am writing.

The macro needs to locate the file with a partial name match; if found then open it and define the workbook as `wb1`, if not found then return an error. Current code below partially inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846874/excel-macro-to-open-file-with-partial-filename).

So far the macro can locate and open the file with partial name match using the `FileSystemObject` to grab the current folder path, but I can't work out how to then define `wb1` with the partial name match.

Is there a way to get the full name of the file once the partial match is successful and thus define `wb1` from that?

```
Sub anotherTest()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fldBase As Folder

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    'determining current folder location based on where the dashboard file is
    Set fldBase = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    For Each Item In fldBase.Files
        If InStr(Item.Name, "*Audit Sheet*") Then
            Workbooks.Open (fldBase & "\" & Item.Name) '<-- Open workbook
            Set wb1 = Workbooks(fldBase & "\" & Item.Name) '<-- set workbook to wb1, THIS BIT DOESNT WORK
        Else
            MsgBox "File not found" '<-- if not found exit sub after showing error
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    'Rest of the macro

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open fldBase & "\" & myPath` and remove the second line in your code should do it.

Comment: The comment above is exactly what I was thinking, but where do you get the value for `myPath`?, should that just be `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Item)`

Comment: Also, remove the asterisks from the `InStr` - you can't use wildcards in there.

Comment: @CLR ah my bad that was my fault, I was trying different things and ended up pasting the half transitioned code! Argh, let me go back and at least change it so the post makes some sense for future context about where I was getting myself tied up in knots.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, thank you for your help, you are right that does work.

Comment: Your code would display the _File not found_ message each time it looked at a file that didn't match the criteria.  It could also attempt to open a workbook that isn't an Excel file - it could find _My*Audit Sheet*.bas_ for instance.  `FileSystemObject` has a `GetExtensionName` property name and you could check if `fso.GetExtensionName(Item) LIKE "xls*"`.

Comment: You can do this using the built in `Dir()` function. [TechOnTheNet: MS Excel: How to use the DIR Function (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code currently works on the basis that there is only ever one file that matches your `*Audit Sheet*` pattern. If there are 2 or more, then it will open them all but only point `wb1` at the latest.

I assume this isn't what you want.

The following will open the first that it finds (so you might want to tighten up your pattern?) :

```
Sub Test()

    Dim fldBase As String
    Dim filefound As String

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    fldBase = "C:\yourbasefolder"
    filefound = Dir(fldBase & "\" & "*Audit Sheet*.xlsm")

    If filefound = "" Then
        MsgBox "File not found" '<-- if not found exit sub after showing error
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fldBase & "\" & filefound)
    End If

    'Rest of the macro

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this works, but does this not mean that the wb1 gets opened every time it is called?

Comment: Yes. Is that not what you want? Or did you want it to check if the file is open already first? Or did you want it to open *every file* that matched the pattern, set wb1 to each file in turn and do stuff with it, perhaps before closing it and moving on to the next?

Comment: Oh no I definitely want it to open the Audit Sheet, but I assumed that it'd be easier to open it first once, then define the wb1 from its name. Or is it equivalent to use it the way you have written it?

Comment: Exactly. `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open...` just does the two steps in one.

Comment: Ah, I see so it doesn't cause more computational processes when called, when it's open already it just refers to the already open wb?

Comment: I think we need to be clear on what you mean by open already and what circumstances would cause that. If the file is open before this routine runs, then it will error at the `Set` line. The code will need to trap that possibility before opening the file.

Comment: Let me explain briefly, the routine should start and open `wb1`, then using `Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(2)` it is called to define the sheet who's tables will be updated by the macro. Once all the copying/updating is done `wb1` is saved and closed. Before adding the check for the presence of `wb1` with partial filename match I was using `Workbooks.Open (fldBase & "\" & "On-Call Audit Sheet V01.XLSM")` followed by `Set wb2 = Workbooks("On-Call Audit Sheet V01.XLSM")` I just assumed it was a more appropriate way of writing it as I was opening it once.