# VBA, File path dynamic date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that is placed in a folder, but the date is unknown to me, is there anyway I can pick it up regardless of the date?

```
FilePath = "\\0_Received\Business_Level_Report_yyyymmdd.xlsx"
```

The file name will be for example Business_Level_Report_20200729

The date will be unknown but it is the only file with Business Level Report as its prefix.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this solution here: [VBA partial file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846874/excel-macro-to-open-file-with-partial-filename)

You can likely modify this just a bit to get what you're looking for.
For example, in your case you might try this:

```
myPath = "\\0_Received\"
fname = Dir(myPath & "Business_Level_Report*")
```

For example, this code opens the workbook named **Business_Level_Report_blah_blah_blah** without having to specify blah_blah_blah:

[image]

Here's the code if you want to run it, too:

```
Private Sub whatever()

Dim fname As Variant
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "C:\Users\beckj\"
fname = Dir(myPath & "Business_Level_Report*")

If fname <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open (myPath & fname)
    MsgBox "File is open."
Else
    MsgBox "ERROR."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can do this in one variable? ie just `mypath = "\\0_Received\Business_Level_Report_*.xlsx"`  ? However this doesnt seem to work as it actually looks for the `*` now.

Comment: @excelguy -  I have edited the answer to give an example of how a **partial filename** can be given to open the workbook.

Comment: @excelguy - The `Dir()` function gives you the ability to use **the * wildcard**. Otherwise, the * is considered a character like the rest of it in that `String`.

Comment: it seems to open but im getting error `Object variable or With block variable not set`

Comment: @excelguy - that's going to have to be somewhere else in your code. As for opening a partial filename, I think this answer works. If you'd open another question with your VBA code in it, then I can try to help find the error, too.

Answer (score 1):

For taday:

```
FilePath = "\\0_Received\Business_Level_Report_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```

for "07/29/2020"

```
Dim D as Date
D = cDate("07/29/2020")
FilePath = "\\0_Received\Business_Level_Report_" & Format(D, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```

Or if you do not care about a specific date, you must iterate between the folder workbooks and choose the appropriate one in this way:

```
If fileName like "*Business_Level_Report########.xlsx" then 
    FilePath = fileName
End If
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt describe it properly. For 07/29/2020, it could be any date here. What if it was 08/05/2020 ?

Comment: @excelguy: You simple replace `D = cDate("07/29/2020")` with `D = cDate("07/05/2020")`. Otherwise, what would you like? Excel to guess the date you are thinking about...? :) Or you need to open every workbook containing in their name something like yyyymmdd?

Comment: yes lol.  I  mean I wont know the date of the file, I dont want to hardcode it :(

Comment: @excelguy: If it is only a single workbook having in name "Business_Level_Report", look of the adapted code, last variant...